# Opera Mini User-Agent string does not contain 'opera mini'

Tags: http-headers, user-agent, opera-mini

Our NodeJS + Express web app has a lot of users who use Opera mini, as the proxy browser helps them save data, and because a lot of them use feature phones.

My query is this:

When we try to intercept the request from Opera Mini, the `user-agent-string` is `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; en-US; ONE A2003 Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 OPR/15.0.2125.101257 Mobile Safari/537.36`

Opera's documentation says [here](https://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-user-agent-strings-opera-15-and-beyond/) that

> Opera Mini continues to use Presto on the server, and its UA string is unchanged; it contains the string "Opera Mini".

There is an `x-requested-with: "com.opera.mini.native"` in the header as well.

My question is, why is the `Mozilla` `user-agent` string showing up instead of `opera-mini`? I tried on `Extreme` as well as `High` savings modes. The `user-agent` is identical.

What am I missing?

Comment: See [History of the browser user-agent string](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. That was a hilarious read and it answers the Mozilla part. But my question still remains - why does it not say Opera on the `user-agent` string? Though old, the article says that the string should be something of this sort for Opera: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; en) Opera 9.51, or Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; U; en; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061208 Firefox/2.0.0 Opera 9.51, or Opera/9.51 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)`

Opera's own docs say: its UA string is unchanged; it contains the string "Opera Mini" for Opera Mini

Answer (score 2):

If I access our site using Opera Mini's extreme data saving mode, I get a different UA string from the one I get when I access it in normal mode.

Normal mode:

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30 OPR/22.0.2254.113472

Extreme mode:

Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/22.0.2254/60.271; U; en) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16

The only identifier in the first UA string is "OPR".

Answer (score 1):

Opera Mini disable compress mode on Android by default then you use Wi-Fi and render as native mode (default render engine), practically like WebView.

Opera Mini UA contains Opera Mini only in compress mode.